# How to write multiple line property value using PropertiesConfiguration?

Tags: java, properties, apache-commons-config

I have a properties file where a property has a comma-separated list value. How can I write these property values so that they span multiple lines? (Maybe a backslash after the comma?)

I can't find anything about this or at least about escaping comma to comma and backslash.

Comment: Can you please clarify, i'm not sure what you are trying to do

Comment: I have a property what has a multi line valie, eg:
key1 = val1,\
       val2,\
       val3
key2 = hello

val1,val2,val3 are in separate lines, but when PropertiesConfigurations writes them to a file, it will write them in one line

Comment: ah you are talking about how it writes it... ok

Answer (score 194):

If you mean the following; that just relies on backslash + end-of-line. I just found it documented in:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html

```
primes = 2,\
    3,\
    5,\
    7,\
    11
```

Answer (score 29):

Check the [User Guide for Properties files](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/userguide/howto_properties.html):

[Special Characters and Escaping](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/userguide/howto_properties.html#Special_Characters_and_Escaping):

> If you need a special character in a property like a line feed, a
>   tabulation or an unicode character, you can specify it with the same
>   escaped notation used for Java Strings. The list separator ("," by
>   default), can also be escaped:
>
> `key = This \n string \t contains \, escaped \\ characters \u0020`

Backslashes are more difficult.

[Lists and arrays](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/userguide/howto_properties.html#Lists_and_arrays):

> You can specify a list of values in your properties file by using the
>   same key on several lines:
>
> ```
> # chart colors
> colors.pie = #FF0000;
> colors.pie = #00FF00;
> colors.pie = #0000FF;
> ```

Answer (score 29):

You need to combine the `\n` character inside the content and the line continuation escape (`\<eol>` at end of line) to get a multi line property actually be represented in the properties file and in the returned value:

```
KEY1=first line\n\
second line\n\
last line
KEY2=another key
```

Not sure if commons-configuration can be configured to actually use this syntax for writing.

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be is to use one of properties formats that is  designed to support multi-line values.

XML can handle multi-line properties well, but it has a lot of noise.

MProps: is an example of the format with almost no special formatting required: https://github.com/mprops/mprops-java