# How to store @Query sql in external file for CrudRepository?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm using `spring` with `CrudRepository`s for database connection.

Now I require a quite long (several lines) sql query that I'd prefer to maintain in a file in classpath, rather than directly inside the code.

But how could I achieve this?
My repo looks as follows:

```
@Query(value = "<my very long sql query>", nativeQuery = true) //how to inject file content?
@Modifying
@Transactional
public void executeSpecificSql();
```

Comment: I know this is a bit obvious using the same syntax you usually use for `@Value`? i.e. `@Query(value = "${my.property.name}", nativeQuery = true)` and then put it in a properties file that you load?

Comment: Ok I did not know this works. Anyhow, how could I then load a property that is spread over multiple lines?

Comment: To be honest I don't know if it works, I cannot really try at the moment, I'm just suggesting to try it (that's why I posted it as a comment rather than an answer). For your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8975908/how-to-write-multiple-line-property-value-using-propertiesconfiguration

Comment: @membersound you can try https://github.com/VEINHORN/spring-data-sqlfile library.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if your project set up has resources folder, create under `/META-INF/jpa-named-queries.properties` file and add key value pair as `repoClass.methodName=yoursql`. Spring data will pick up.

For longer queries it's probably best to use `xml` properties file with `CDATA` tags: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19128259/1194415

Comment: @see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/test/resources/META-INF/jpa-named-queries.properties

Comment: This solution not answers initial question as it should contain: "quite long (several lines) sql query". Though in config.properties it will be one line or ugly assignment on every new line of code.

Comment: @rajkumar how to get the xml properties file in spring data jpa custom implementation class ?

Comment: Every solution ends up with this. But I have 1000 line sql with several layers of inline views etc. Would prefer to keep in `.sql` file for readability. Is there just no way?

Comment: @membersound Dead link bro

Comment: How does it know which repository to pick up if there is more than one file with similar names under different packages?

Answer (score 17):

Use below steps.

1. Create jpa-named-queries.property file in src/main/resources-->META-INF Folder
   [image]
2. Defile your query in given properties file.
   [image]
   Above screenshot look closely.Here **Group** is Entity name, while **Method should match** with **method define in Repository interface.** Query should have object name instead table name and instead of column name provide variable name given in entity for respective field.
3. Interface method method with property name

   [image: List item]

Comment: This answer is not any different than the accepted one. Thanks for the response though.

Comment: Indeed, tried to provide graphics representation for quick understanding.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from Java 15 you can store queries as [Text blocks](https://www.baeldung.com/java-text-blocks) in a separate class:

```java
public class SomeLongQuery {
    public static final String QUERY = 
        """
        SELECT * 
        FROM table
        WHERE
        ...
        ORDER BY some_column;
        """;
}
```

And use it as a string constant:

```java
@Query(value = SomeLongQuery.QUERY, native = true)
Iterable<SomeEntity> findByLongQuery();
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it fits your setup, but, this can be done by :

1) Adding your query to a hibernate mapping file using the `<sql-query>` tag

```
<sql-query name="MyQuery">.......
```

2) Define a hibernate config file that includes the above file using the `<mapping>` tag

```
<mapping resource="MyQuery.sql.xml"/>
```

3) Defining a persistence file with a property `"hibernate.ejb.cfgfile"` that points to the above config file

```
<property name="hibernate.ejb.cfgfile" value="hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
```

4) Use the above property file to build the `EntityManagerFactory`

Now, the above Query can be used in the Repository method :

```
@Query(name = "MyQuery", nativeQuery = true)
[return type] executeMyQuery();
```