# Spring boot + Jpa queries from properties file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql, named-query

I am working on spring boot + JPA repository methods. here is my simple query method.

```
@Query("SELECT g FROM Greeting g where g.text = :text")
Greeting findGreetingByText(@Param("text") String sText);
```

Is there any way we can configure this query values in properties file instead of hardcode like above method.

for example:

```
@Query("Greet.SelectQuery")
 Greeting findGreetingByText(@Param("text") String sText);
```

//application.properties

```
Greet.SelectQuery=SELECT g FROM Greeting g where g.text = :text
```

Thank you.

Comment: Sure, you probably could with SpEL, but what's the point? You would have to rebuild and retest the app anyway after a change, finding the appropriate query to change would be harder, and knowing which query is executed for a method would be harder too.

Comment: @JB Nizet Yes correct but my application has to execute a list of select queries & sent the result that's it. no other work on those results. this select query changes frequently because of this reason I am thinking instead of changing application every time i want to use properties file.

Comment: you can but probably not recommended. if it changes frequently and storing it in properties file sounds like a code smell to me. is there a way to parameterize the where condition?

Comment: Use `TypedQuery` with `entityManager` like this `TypedQuery<YOUR_ENTITY_CLASS> query = entityManager.createQuery(DbQueries.YOUR_QUERY,
       YOUR_ENTITY_CLASS.class);`

Comment: Have a look at my QLRM project. This has QueryExecutors http://simasch.github.io/qlrm/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to store @Query sql in external file for CrudRepository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27902242/how-to-store-query-sql-in-external-file-for-crudrepository)