# How to refer long query, written in external file, in Spring data jpa @Query

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

- I want to write query (properties or yaml) in external file to load database. -
- This is long query and does not look good to eye when placed inside @Query("long query") in XXXRepository class.
- Is there way to write this query in an external file (properties, yaml, xml or json) and call that file in @Query() in spring data jpa?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to store @Query sql in external file for CrudRepository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27902242/how-to-store-query-sql-in-external-file-for-crudrepository)

Comment: Is this answer relevant? https://stackoverflow.com/a/55667349/1005607 There's a library for this, it looks like.

Answer (score 11):

You can use named queries, where the queries have to be defined in a file called `META-INF/jpa-named-queries.properties`. See the [spring example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/test/resources/META-INF/jpa-named-queries.properties):

```
User.findBySpringDataNamedQuery=select u from User u where u.lastname=?1
```

Reference the query by name in the annotation in your repository, here the [corresponding repository example from spring](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/sample/UserRepository.java):

```
@Query(name = "User.findBySpringDataNamedQuery", countProjection = "u.firstname")
Page<User> findByNamedQueryAndCountProjection(String firstname, Pageable page);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. My query spreads on 500 lines to load data in Neo4j, how I can incorporate such long query in properties file as query spreads on multiple lines. I see one way to add / at end of each line but its not convenient placing \ 500 times. Is there any better way to write query in properties file that spans on multiple lines ?

Comment: Try to define your named query in the [META-INF/orm.xml](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/test/resources/META-INF/orm.xml) instead. But I'm not sure if JPA eats multiline queries, let me know if this works.

Comment: Thanks again for the reply. I tried but it did not work, getting this error,
ERROR 10384 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Error executing Cypher; Code: Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError; Description: Invalid input 'a': expected 'r/R' or 'e/E' (line 1, column 2 (offset: 1))
"dataLoad"

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by [Ralf Stuckert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6223149/ralf-stuckert), use `META-INF/jpa-named-queries.properties` to store named queries

You can use `\` to split the long query into multiple lines.

Example:

```
Customer.findNameNative=\
SELECT C.NAME \
FROM CUST_TABLE C \
WHERE CONDITIONS
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're finding a place to put your big query string as readable? Like Mybatis xml. As my knowledge There is no method to do that in data jpa.

But you can put that big query inside of a  Stored Procedure and call it easily like below.

```sql
Call your_stored_procedure_name(param1,param2):
```