# how to get queries from jpa-named-queries.properties

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, nativequery, hibernate-native-query

I'm using **jpa-named-queries.properties** file for writing HQL and native queries for my repository interfaces.

now the problem here is when i write native query, returned values i cant directly cast into Entity as column defined as Long in entity are now changed to BigInteger. PFB

[image]

i got the solution also for this to cast native query to my entity but i want my query to stay in **jpa-named-queries.properties** , i dont want it to hardcode in my DAO implementation.

```
Query q = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery("select * from todo", Todo.class);
    List<Todo> l = q.getResultList();
```

above code works fine i.e. i can write native query and it will return data in entity format also.

is there any way i can read this query from **jpa-named-queries.properties** **???**

**jpa-named-queries.properties** file

```
TodoRepo.getList=select * from todo
```

**TodoRepo.java**

```
@Repository
public interface TodoRepo extends JpaRepository<Todo, Long> {
      @Query(nativeQuery = true)
      public void getList();
}
```

Comment: First, try to read from the properties file([Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38281512/how-to-read-data-from-java-properties-file-using-spring-boot)) then pass the string in `createNativeQuery`

Comment: Thanks @Rono for suggestion, one doubt as already this file is loaded in context and Repository interfaces are reading this file, is it good idea to load same property file as a property source ??
just want to understand if loading it twice for different purpose will cause any performance problems or any thing like that ?

Comment: If you already loaded in context then use [like](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44996862/4207306)

Comment: thats the problem , i know it is in context as repository interfaces are reading it but, i don't know how to read it as it was picked-up by spring boot automatically once i placed it in **\src\main\resources\META-INF\jpa-named-queries.properties** .
any suggestion how can i read this file ?

Comment: What happened if you use `@Query(name = "TodoRepo.getList",...` ? I am not sure about it's worked for JPQL only or not.

Comment: yes it works but again i'll not be able to map returned values to todo entiity class , all Long values are being converted to BigInteger.(as attached above image)

i just need to pass this query in getEntityManager().createNativeQuery() method to work it properly.