# In Spring data jpa, how to use external sql file having multiple queries in @Query annotation

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, named-query

I have a requirement to delete an entity, let's say, `main_entity` and this entity has many dependent entities. So, I need to perform deletion in this manner:

```
delete from dependent_entity_1 where main_entity_id IN :entity_ids;
delete from dependent_entity_2 where main_entity_id IN :entity_ids;
delete from dependent_entity_3 where main_entity_id IN :entity_ids;
delete from dependent_entity_4 where main_entity_id IN :entity_ids;
delete from main_entity where id IN ::entity_ids;
```

Since, there are a lot of dependent entities, I want to put the deletion query in a separate file instead of hard-coding inside the repository class.

I tried using named query as mentioned here: [How to refer long query, written in external file, in Spring data jpa @Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44937306/how-to-refer-long-query-written-in-external-file-in-spring-data-jpa-query)

The properties file look like this:

```
MainEntity.deleteEntities=delete from dependent_entity_1 where main_entity_id IN :entity_id;\
delete from dependent_entity_2 where main_entity_id IN :entity_id;\
delete from dependent_entity_3 where main_entity_id IN :entity_id;\
delete from dependent_entity_4 where main_entity_id IN :entity_id;\
delete from main_entity where id IN ::entity_id;\
```

It is working for a single query but for multiple queries it is giving an exception: `Named parameter not bound :entity_ids;`

So, it might not support executing multiple queries.

Is there any way to do this or am I doing anything incorrectly here?

Comment: I might be wrong, but I thought the Query annotation would only support issuing a single statement - this file you are showing is multiple statements. IMO You are better off writing a method implementation that reads your file and issues each as a separate query/statement, or putting something like that in the DB as a stored procedure

Comment: @Chris You are correct. I ended up implementing it via stored procedures.