# How to populate @Query value for native queries in Spring boot Repository when Queries are stored as external files

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Similar question has been asked and answered back in 2015 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27902242/how-to-store-query-sql-in-external-file-for-crudrepository).

However , rather than storing queries in XML files , I would like to store them in external .sql files and read query from there.
To achieve this in our spring boot application - 2.1.5.RELEASE with Java 8 , we are storing queries in resources folder as below

`src/main/resources
   - queries
     - A.sql
     - B.sql`

To read the above queries , I'm reading them in QueryReader class as below

```
@Component
public class QueryReader {

    public String getQueryFromFile(String fileName) {
        System.out.println("getQueryFromFile() : " + fileName);
        return this.convertInputStreamToString(this.getTemplateAsStream(fileName));
    }




     private InputStream getTemplateAsStream(String queryFileName){
            ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
            InputStream iStream =classLoader.getResourceAsStream("queries/" + queryFileName);

            return iStream;
        }
}
```

And to use it anywhere in the code , i'm having below class , so that i can call it's methods

```
@Component
public class MyQueries {


    @Autowired
    private QueryReader qfr;

    public String queryErroredRecords() {
        return qfr.getQueryFromFile("A.sql");
    }
```

While using it with JDBCTemplate , this works as expected but when I'm trying to use this method from @Query annotation from Repository , i'm not able to do so with errors as below.

Repository Code

```
@Repository
public interface AdminRepository extends JpaRepository<OrderBackupRecordEO, BigDecimal>{

    @Autowired
    public MyQueries queries;


@Query(value = queries.queryErroredRecords() , nativeQuery= true)
    List<String> findX();
}
```

Above repository is giving errors as below :

1.The value for annotation attribute Query.value must be a constant expression (For @Query annotation)

2.The blank final field queries may not have been initialized (For @Autowired annotation)

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 2):

I would just add a note that may be helpful for you.

Your solution cannot work just because in java in an interface all the fields (variables) are by default **public**, **static** and **final** and that why you cannot *@Autowire* any dependencies inside the interface.

That's why it works for your case for JDBCTemplate (which is a class) and doesn't work for spring data repository (which is an interface).

Comment: Yes , you are right .Thought there might other way or annotation to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Spring already has a solution "from the box", you don't need to make all these manipulations.

```
@Repository
public interface AdminRepository extends JpaRepository<OrderBackupRecordEO, BigDecimal> {

    List<String> findX();
}
```

File `src/main/resources/META-INF/jpa-named-queries.properties`:

```
OrderBackupRecordEO.findX=\
    SELECT record FROM OrderBackupRecordEO record WHERE ...
```

That's all! No any loading, manipulations, manual handling - an implementation is hidden in Spring - very simple and reliable.

Comment: Every solution ends up with this. But I have 1000 line sql with several layers of inline views etc. Would prefer to keep in `.sql` file for readability. Is there just no way?